# Как перебрать объекты textBox в цикле?

Tags: c#

Приветствую! Как перебрать несколько объектов textBox в цикле на C# Sharp,?
Пояснение:
Имеется двумерный массив - матрица, который нужно заполнить в цикле элементами находящимися в объектах textBox

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос плохо понятен. Если у вас есть некая форма и на ней размещены контролы (каждый из которых - это textbox), то их можно перебрать в цикле:

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
    // Выполняем действия над контролом
}
```

Если на форме есть еще что-то, помимо textbox, то надо смотреть каждый контрол. Также, если контролы лежат не прямо в форме, а в каком-либо контейнере, надо просмотривать коллекцию контейнера.

В дополнение согласно уточнению вопроса. Строки, которые содержатся в конкретном контроле, получаются через свойство Lines

```
string[] lines = textbox.Lines;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью LINQ:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x is TextBox).Select(x=>x as TextBox))
{

}
```

Comment: Тогда уж

    foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TextBox>())

Answer (score 2):

Некропост, но вдруг кому пригодится.
Можно обойтись без LINQ.

```
foreach (TextBox c in form1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Чтобы отформатировать часть ответа как код, просто выделите текст и нажмите кнопку {} на тулбаре.

Answer (score 1):

А если у Вас текст боксы находятся, например на панелях или в групбоксах то добраться до них можно так...

Вызов функции: SetNullInTextBox(this.Controls);

```
    private void SetNullInTextBox(Control.ControlCollection control)
    {
        foreach (Control _control in control)
        {
            if (_control is TextBox & String.IsNullOrEmpty(_control.Text))
                ((TextBox)_control).Text = "0";
            if (_control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                SetNullInTextBox(_control.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
```